# CSS/Javascript accurate timing animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, web

I have a specific situation where I need to display buttons which flicker at certain frequencies. It is of utmost importance that the buttons flicker as accurately as possible (for example: one button at 5Hertz, another button at 10Hertz, etc..) I am currently using CSS keyframes to achieve this, for example:

```
  .flashing{
      -webkit-animation: 0.2s flash linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: 0.2s flash linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: 0.2s flash linear infinite;
      animation: 0.2s flash linear infinite;
   }

    @keyframes flash {
           0% { background-color: red; }
           50% { opacity: white; }
       }
```

Is there a way to increase the timing accuracy further than this by utilising CSS? (for example, syncing with the browser's refresh rate?). The flickering mostly occurs at the right frequency. However, unfortunately I do get large, unexplainable spikes in the readings (I am using an external scientific instrument to measure frequencies). I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate these large spikes in the readings altogether, or if there was a way to minimise them significantly.

In short: I am trying to find the best way to display CSS timing animations as accurately as possible. Or else is there a way to achieve this accurate timing by using Javascript/Jquery instead?

Does anyone know anything about this?

Thank you

Comment: Really good question. Are you seeing timings off considerably? I don't have an answer but I wonder if you couldn't use Javascript (I know you asked for CSS) to "rectify" the flashing periodically if it falls out of sync.

Comment: well ... HTM/CSS is for user, and our perception is limited, so what is the need of accurate thing like this ? especially when it comes to low value like 0.2s

Comment: Actually, most times the results are good. However, unfortunately occasionally I get very large spikes in readings, and then this goes down immediately. It is not happening too often but to give you an idea this does happen around 5 times within 5 minutes. @CharlieDalsass

Comment: It is required for an assignment task. And 0.2 is an example it is to be increased/decreased to show different frequencies. @TemaniAfif

Comment: What do you mean rectify the flashing periodically? @CharlieDalsass

Comment: I'm not sure how you are taking readings, but I'm assuming after some time, something falls 'out of sync' with expected number of cycles. Take a look at the section, "Adding the animation event listeners" in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations. It seems it would be possible to adjust the speed periodically if it falls behind or goes ahead of expected.

Comment: @CharlieDalsass Thanks for this. However, I am not sure how I can properly use it in my case. Could you provide me with a sample code please?

Comment: What browser do you need to support, and if possible a simple codepen, would help

Comment: @Questionnaire could you show me some of the data for the readings? I'm wondering if it's possible these errors are from the (reading) equipment itself.